# Preposition: ... struggles (n) in establishing

Tags: prepositions

> The history of UI in Canada stretches back to the country’s early **struggles** **in** **establishing** a federally regulated unemployment program.

I am not sure if 'in' is the correct preposition here, although I prefer it. I googled "struggles in" and there is about half a million hits, "struggles at" returns only 700,000. I looked at The Guardian which does not have any entry with "struggles in establishing/forming/creating" or anything similar. Using *at/over/of* just is not clicking with me. I have looked at the other posts in this site but they are regarding the choice of preposition  with the verb *struggle*. Can anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adverbial phrases:

In is fine here. If you are going to google, forget struggles. Try: in [forming, establishing, creating]. That adverbial phrasing is fine.

I am having difficulties in trying to explain this. :)
They have issues in writing good legal briefs.

It's noun + in [gerund]

Answer (score 2):

'In' is correct. You could also avoid the preposition and write: struggles to establish.

Comment: +1 I originally posted my own answer that said the same thing—before I realized you'd beaten me to it.